# Reference df1 to check validity in df2 and create a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with three columns denoting three zones of countries a user can be subscribed.In each of the three columns there is a list of countries (some countries are in all three columns)

In another dataframe I have a list of users and the countries they are in.

The objective is to identify what zone the user is in, if any and remark that they are or are not allowed to use the service in that country.

df1 contains the country the user is in and the zone the user is subscribed to, as well as other fields.

df2 contains the zones available and the list of countries for that zone, as well as other fields.

```
df1.head()

name   alias3  status_y country    
Thetis Z1      active   Romania
Demis  Z1      active   No_country
Donis  Z1      active   Sweden
Rhona  Z3      active   Germany
Theau  Z2      active   Bangladesh

df2.head()

Zone 1   Zone 2  Zone 3
ALBANIA  ALBANIA ALBANIA
BELGIUM  BELGIUM BELGIUM
BULGARIA AUSTRIA AUSTRIA
NaN      CROATIA CROATIA
NaN      NaN     DENMARK
```

I have written conditions listing one of the three zones the user is subscribed to.

I have written values that select the country the user is in, and checks if that country is in the zone the user is subscribed to.

```
conditions = [
    (df1['alias3']=='Z1'),
    (df1['alias3']=='Z2'),
    (df1['alias3']=='Z3')
]

values = [
    df1['country'].str.upper().isin(country_zone['Zone 1']),
    df1['country'].str.upper().isin(country_zone['Zone 2']),
    df1['country'].str.upper().isin(country_zone['Zone 3'])
]

df1['valid_country'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Is there a better way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way would be:

```
def valid(sdf):
    zone = sdf.alias3.iat[0][-1]
    sdf["valid_country"] = sdf.country.str.upper().isin(df2[f"Zone {zone}"])
    return sdf

df1 = df1.groupby("alias3").apply(valid)
```

- `groupby` `df1` over the `alias3`s and then
- `apply` a function to the groups that checks if the `upper`ed country names in the group's `country` column are in the respective column of `df2` and stores the result in a column named `valid_country`

Another way would be to alter `df2` a bit:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace("one ", "")
df2 = (
    df2.melt(var_name="alias3", value_name="country")
    .dropna()
    .assign(valid_country=True)
)
df2.country = df2.country.str.capitalize()
```

- Transforming the column names from `'Zone 1/2/3'` to `'Z1/2/3'`
- `melt`-ing: the Zone-column names into a column named `alias3` with the respective country names in a column named `country`
- Dropping the `NaN`s
- Adding a column named `valid_country` all `True`
- Capitalizing the country names

And then:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=["alias3", "country"], how="left")
df1.valid_country[df1.valid_country.isna()] = False
```

- Left-`merge`-ing the result with `df1` on the columns `alias3` and `country`
- Filling in the missing `False` in the column `valid_country`

Comment: @SeamusMcMillen Was this helpful? If so, please consider [upvoting/accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).